# Possible to convert 15in speakers into 18in?

Tags: audio, speakers

I need some advice. I want to start djing doing outdoor events. I bought the equipment I need however the Gemini speakers are 15 inch ones and I'm wondering if I can convert them into 18 inch ones by replacing the cones??

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I've pumped in quite a bit into this so I want to try and make it work as cost effectively as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you *actually* mean take the cones off the magnets & replace them with bigger cones? if so, forget it. the engineering tolerances are measures in microns, not inches.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? I can't think of much benefit of 18" drivers over 15" ones.

Comment: Even if you take out you 15" and throw it away, cut a larger hole and jam an 18" in there, is still not a good idea. The speaker cabinet was designed for a 15" so putting a different size cone in there is going to change the dynamic of that box.

Comment: Also, I prefer the sound from some 15" bins because they can sound warmer and clearer in many situations. Bigger is not always better

Answer (score 2):

Deity no.  That's like converting a dachshound to a dobermann by replacing the legs.  The speakers are designed and manufactured and tested and calibrated as one item.  You cannot even exchange the cone of one speaker by any old cone of an arbitrary equal-sized speaker.

Comment: +1 for a dog analogy to a woof-er question.

Answer (score -1):

18 Inch drivers can be very sloppy in the bottom end, your better to stick with the 15's as they will give you a bit more punch for what you are doing.

As for converting them - yes you can, by buying 18 inch speakers :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can upgrade your 15" speakers to 18".

Everything works perfect if you detach the 15" basket(cone housing  and replace it with 18" basket.

1. remove the 15" cone together with the spider and coil.
2. detach the metal cage,  normally it's glued at the top of the iron of the magnetic casing.

Some speaker makers use screws to hold them while others don't.

Whichever way you find it,  carefully loosen or detach it without harming nor shifting the magnetic casing and balancing.

3. replace it with 18" basket.
4. then detach the 15" cone from the spider and install 18" with the spider and coil.

If the spider differs,  look for a matching one.

Goodluck.

Comment: Now, this is an advice I would never give and never follow.